# How Do I install Wowza Streaming Engine on Google Cloud?

Tags: android, video-streaming, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, wowza

I'm trying to install Wowza streaming engine manager on google cloud, but it is not working.  I am using [this tutorial](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?560-How-to-set-up-Wowza-for-Google-Compute-Engine).  I create my wowza streaming engine image, firewall rules, and instance with no problem. However, when I test my instance through the browser via the created external ip.

```
http://instance-external-ip-address:8088/login.htm.
```

the page fails to load.  For my vminstance, in the metadata section i am entering WZA_wowzaServerLicenseKey as key and my trial license key as value.  I am also entering WZA_startupPackageURL for key and leaving value as blank so the default package will be used.  What am i doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you paste the standalone wowza start up logs here ?

#cd /usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/bin/
#./shutdown.sh
#./startup.sh

Answer (score 2):

According to the tutorial :

- did you add the required startup package (Pick a startup package and get...) ? Default = VOD + Live
- the tutorial seems to indicate that if you want the default startup page, you shouldn't specify a key with WZA_startupPackageURL (To specify a startup package: In Key, enter WZA_startupPackageURL... Remember that if you don't specify a startup package, the Default startup package is used.).
- did you also properly add the firewall rule for tcp:8088 and tcp:1935 ?
- after Tutorial#Start the instance: please check that your instance is properly running https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances#listingvms

Answer (score 0):

If you add the firewall rules in Google's developers console, be sure to set the 'Source IP Ranges' to **0.0.0.0/0** and not just **0.0.0.0**